# Can Azure Static WebApp pull an image from Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, azure-static-web-app

We are currently utilizing the [Azure Static Web App Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-static-web-app?view=azure-devops) in Azure Devops pipelines to deploy our static Angular application and this is working fine.

Is it also possible to configure Static Web App to pull an image from Azure Container Registry similar to how Azure WebApps do? I could not find any documentation in this regard.

Thanks,
Param

Answer (score 1):

I think we can't deploy a container app on azure static web app . you have to use azure app service to deploy container app.